# Join two tables with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got table `Visit` with columns like `VisitID`, `PatientID`, `DoctorID` etc. and also column `PrescriptionID`. In table `Prescription` there are columns `PrescriptionID` and `DrugID` (together they are my primary key). One prescription can have many drugs, so there will be something like:

PrescriptionID: 1 DrugID: 38
PrescriptionID: 1 DrugID: 278
PrescriptionID: 1 DrugID: 7

In `Visit` table there will be inserted '1' value as `PrescriptionID`. But now I can't join those two tables with foreign key, because not every visit have prescription, so `PrescriptionID` can be null and I've got error that column must be primary key or must be unique. How can I join those tables in another way?

Comment: Please show the query that causes this error.

Comment: ALTER TABLE Prescription ADD FOREIGN KEY (PrescriptionID) REFERENCES Visit(PrescriptionID)

Comment: What do you actually need `PrescriptionID` for? From what you said there is 1:1* relationship between `VisitID` and `PrescriptionID`. Can't `Prescription` table use `VisitID` as foreign column?

Comment: `PrescriptionID` has to be in specific format (20 characters, each means something etc.), so it can't relate to VisitID.

Comment: I didn't mean to get rid of `PrescriptionID` completely - just make `Prescriptions` table use FK to `VisitID` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be talking about two distinct issues here.

One issue is, you want to allow nulls in a referencing column. That is easy, you just need to define the column as nullable *and* as a foreign key. What that key should reference is another question, which leads us to the other of the two issues I can see in your question.

The error about the column having to be primary key or unique has to do with the fact that the referencing table uses a *single* column to reference a compound (consisting of two columns) key. And you can't reference only part of the key, because a reference must be to a specific *single* row and your `Visit.PrescriptionID` value is likely to reference more than one (and rightly so, because the rows in the referenced table aren't really prescriptions, but prescription items). That is why you are told that the column must be primary key or unique.

Therefore, I suggest changing your schema as follows:

1. Let your `Prescription` table contain only prescriptions as entities. Even if there are no other attribute than a key, let it be stored in its own table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Presciption (
     PrescriptionID int
       IDENTITY  /* just an assumption */
       CONSTRAINT PK_Prescription PRIMARY KEY
   );
   ```
2. Your present `Prescription` table should be renamed to something like `PrescriptionItem` or `PrescriptionDrug`, following your singular noun naming convention. Its `PrescriptionID` column would be a foreign key referencing `Prescription.PrescriptionID`, something like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE PresciptionDrug (
     PrescriptionID int NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT FK_PrescriptionDrug_Prescription
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCING Prescription (PrescriptionID),
     DrugID int NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT FK_PrescriptionDrug_Drug
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCING Drug (DrugID),
     CONSTRAINT PK_PrescriptionDrug
       PRIMARY KEY (PrescriptionID, DrugID)
   );
   ```
3. Now you can define the foreign on `Visit.PrescriptionID` like this:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Visit
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Visit_Prescription
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCING Prescription (PrescriptionID)
   ;
   ```

   Don't forget to make sure the column is nullable if you want to make prescriptions optional for visits. (Nullable foreign keys are perfectly fine in SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the table structure should be

```
Visit (VisitID, Time, .....) --no prescriptionID
Prescription (PrescriptionID, ..... , VisitID) --VisitID as FK
PrescriptionDrugs(PrescriptionID, DrugID) -- Both columns as PK
```

Then your query would be

```
SELECT v.VisitID FROM Visit v
LEFT JOIN Prescription p ON v.VisitID = p.VisitID
LEFT JOIN PrescriptionDrugs pd ON p.PrescriptionID = pd.PrescriptionID
```

That would give you something like

```
VisitID        PrescriptionID      DrugID
101            ABC                 Anti-Bio
101            ABC                 Asprin
102            BAC                 Anti-Bio
```

Meaning 2 drugs for `Visit 101` and 1 drug for `Visit 102`

Anyway, with your current schema, try this

```
select v.visitid, v.presid, p.drugid 
from visit v 
left join prescription p on v.presid = p.presid
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to do:

```
select *
  from Visit as V left outer join
    Prescription as P on P.PrescriptionId = V.PrescriptionId
```

This will return all visits and any applicable prescriptions.  Visits without prescriptions will result in output rows that have no prescription data.